# Detect contours with imagemagick

Tags: java, image, imagemagick

I'm trying to detect rectangles in a image, I know this is possible with OpenCv but I was thinking of using ImageMagick.
 The question is, is it possible to do it with ImageMagick? I was looking to find a equivalent `findContours` function from OpenCV in ImageMagick but I couldn't find one?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Here's a not fully robust version that achieves what I have need for [simply connected regions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simply_connected_space). It plays on the fact that there are no holes for the regions the contours bound and that no region makes contact with the coordinate 0,0. Both are not likely in my application so I'm able to exploit these facts to establish the background. I can also exploit that I know in advance what the color of my contour is, which I've indicated with `#ContourColor`

```
convert inputImage.jpg -fill black         +opaque  #ContourColor
                       -fill blue          -draw    "color 0,0 floodfill"
                       -fill #ContourColor -opaque  black
                       -fill white         -opaque  #ContourColor
                       -fill black         -opaque  blue
                       outputImage.jpg
```

Here's the breakdown of each step...

> 1. Fill everything not ContourColor as black
> 2. Fill background as blue, assuming no simply connected object touches top left pixel 0,0
> 3. Fill all black interiors as ContourColor to fill contours
> 4. Replace ContourColor for White to establish foreground
> 5. Replace blue background as black to establish background

It would be very useful for ImageMagick to implement the same contour functionality as OpenCV, but I'm in the same boat as you where I'm just looking for a simple tool to tease out some regions that I happen to be hand drawing and wish to make use of in some image processing regression tests. I don't want to write a full blown application to make these segmentation comparisons and am hoping I can get by scripting some ImageMagick magic!

Answer (score 0):

Contours of this image will be double lines due to the thickness of the outline and text. For example to get the contours (outline) of the green box, use

```
convert HetI7.jpg -fuzz 20% -fill white +opaque green1 -morphology edgeout diamond:1 -negate green_outline.png
```

[image]

But perhaps you just want the green box and not its outline.

```
convert HetI7.jpg -fuzz 40% -fill white +opaque green1 green_region.png
```

[image]